# Bitrix drag_n_drop - загрузчик не работает в модальном окне

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Делаю форму с прикреплением файлов с помощью bitrix:main.file.input с шаблоном drag_n_drop. Вывожу форму простую страницу - все работает прекрасно, но стоит только поместить ее в модальное окно, всплывают ошибки в скриптах шаблона компонента. Подскажите почему это может быть?

```html
<?//Подключаем модуль инфоблоков
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$IBLOCK_ID = 15; //ИД инфоблока с которым работаем
?>

<form name="add_my_ankete" action="/add_form_result.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Название
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" value="">
<br></br>
    Свойство Строка
    <input type="text" name="line" maxlength="255" value="">
    <br></br>
    <label><input name='service_dop[]' type="checkbox" value="<?= $arSect['ID']; ?>"> <?= $arSect['NAME']; ?></label>
    <?}}?>
    <br></br>

   <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.file.input", "drag_n_drop",
    array(
    "INPUT_NAME"=>"file_pol",
    "MULTIPLE"=>"Y",
    "MODULE_ID"=>"iblock",
    "MAX_FILE_SIZE"=>"",//25000000 25mb
    "ALLOW_UPLOAD"=>"A",
    "INPUT_CAPTION" => "Добавить файлы",
    "INPUT_VALUE" => $_POST["file_pol"]
    ),
    false
    );
   ?>
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: Ну и какие ошибки всплывают? Как нам помочь Вам если мы не знаем какие ошибки? Телепатия с утра плохо работает, добавьте в вопрос ошибки.

Comment: @NikolajSarry добавил скриншот с ошибками

Answer (score 0):

В модальный вызов добавить:

```
$APPLICATION->ShowAjaxHead();
```